# Alternatives to Azure DDoS Protection for Azure hosted applications

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, ddos

I am looking for alternative options to Azure DDoS protection for protecting my Azure hosted web applications. Azure DDoS is $2944/month which is too pricey for us.

We currently have several web apps hosted in Azure sitting behind an Azure App Gateway (with WAF). Would it be possible to add DDoS protection from a 3rd party vendor such as AWS Shield or Cloudflare without reconfiguring our web apps to use a new layer 7 gateway? Or is the only option to replace the Azure App Gateway with a different vendor gateway? Is the DDoS solution generally tied to whichever layer 7 gateway is being used?

Ideally I would like to be able to enable a DDoS layer of protection without having to restructure our Azure services if that's at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I'm looking to implement a more robust DDoS solution including UDP/SYN flood protection.

Answer (score 0):

There are some enhancements and updates in the Azure network security portfolio, including Azure DDoS Protection, which will be announced in Microsoft Ignite 2022 from October 12 to 14.

There will be a public preview of latest Azure DDOS Protection SKU at Ignite (10/12/2022), and the pricing for that would be quite less. You can wait till the announcement and consider that.

Refer : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-network-security-blog/microsoft-ignite-2022-explore-what-s-new-in-azure-network/ba-p/3645142

Alternatively – Azure Front Door with WAF and Cloudflare are also valid options.
You can enable Cloudflare DDoS layer of protection without having to restructure the existing Azure services. DDoS solution is not tied to whichever layer 7 gateway is being used.

Comment: The new DDoS IP Protection SKU is now available in Preview and it's pricing will go into effect on November 1, 2022.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-protection-sku-comparison#ddos-ip-protection

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/ddos-protection/